# Postgresql не возвращает результат, но нет ошибок

Tags: postgresql, pgsql

В базу postgresql стучатся много скриптов, все обращаются через pgbouncer и делают выборки задач через select for update skip locked. В условный 1 из 30 запросов база отдает пустой результат селекта, хотя записи для выборки есть. В логе pgsql, pgbouncer и pdo::errorInfo ошибок нет.

Почему база может не отдавать результат запроса?

Comment: Блокировки быть может?

Comment: @eri Да, вы были правы. Не обратил внимание на очевидную вещь: когда делаешь join, то блокируешь и основную запись и ту, что попала вместе с join'ом.